# how to stop wordpress admin menu from scrolling with page

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

Ive already answered this question but when I came on here I noticed this question hasnt been asked, but the question is:

How do you stop the admin sidebar menu from scrolling with the page?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have for this, is in my themes function, or in a custom plugin file (if you have plugins you are working with) add this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'kaz_stop_sidescroll' );

function kaz_stop_sidescroll(){
  ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #adminmenuwrap  {position: relative!important;}
    </style>
  <?php
}
```

This will only add the styles to the admin area head (similar to wp_head action but for admin area only) and will always override the javascripts "position:fixed" that causes the admin bar to scroll.